# CheckBox check all child checkBox on check

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I simply wanna check all child checkBox when parent is check and uncheck when parent is uncheck.

THX

```
<div class="modal-body">

            @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model[i].Id)
                <div id="@Model[i].Name" class="row" style="width:300px;">
                    <div>
                        <span data-toggle="collapse" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" data-target="#@Model[i].Id"> </span>
                        @Html.Label(Model[i].Name + "("+ (Model[i].LicensesTotal - Model[i].LicensesUsed).ToString()+"/" + Model[i].LicensesTotal.ToString()))


                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model[i].Assigned, new { @class = "pull-right",  @id = @Model[i].Name.ToString() })
                    </div>
                    <div id="@Model[i].Id" class="collapse">


                        @for (int i2 = 0; i2 < Model[i].Plans.Count; i2++)
                        {
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    @Html.Label(Model[i].Plans[i2].Name)
                                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(x=> Model[i].Plans[i2].Assigned, new { @class = "pull-right" })
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                    </div>
                    <hr/>
                </div>

            }

</div>
```

Comment: Write html result element instead of razor.

Comment: Its dynamically  generated so you cant assume the html result will be always the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a special class to the parent checkbox like this,

```
 @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model[i].Assigned, new { @class = "pull-right parent",  @id = @Model[i].Name.ToString() })
```

Then your code will be,

```
$(".parent").change(function() {
  $(this).closest(".row").find(".collapse :checkbox").prop("checked", this.checked);
});
```

- find the parent div with class `row` using `closest(".row")`
- Get all the checkboxes inside the div collapse using `.find(".collapse :checkbox")` (Find will search for the child elements)

Comment: I have this $(":checkbox").change(function (e) to detect the Id

Comment: @FrankSharp then add a special class to the parent checkbox.

Comment: @FrankSharp see the answer now.

Comment: The class event is detected but  $(this).closest(".row").find(".collapse :checkbox").prop("checked", this.checked); not work

Comment: try alert((this).closest(".row").find(".collapse :checkbox").length) and let me know the result

Comment: alert((this).closest(".row").find(".collapse :checkbox").length) do nothing

Comment: misssed $  
alert($(this).closest(".row").find(".collapse :checkbox").length)

Comment: Ah because class="collapse" when is collapse did not see closest(".row") but if its not collapse its work

Comment: ohh ok collapse is dynamically changing. Then you cant use that classname inside the selector.

Comment: Hope you got the answer.

Comment: Edit your answer please